# How to export data from saga or tas into excel?

Tags: raster, export, saga, terrain, whitebox-gat

I want to derive terrain attributes from DEM with saga and whiteBox GAT (SAT). I have problem  in exporting data into excel. 
would you help me?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your post a little? Do you want to export your entire DEM raster to Excel or some distribution of derived terrain attributes (e.g. slope)? What exactly is it you're looking to do? Excel is for spreadsheets and so not normally used with raster data. That's why I wonder if it's simply the distribution of an attribute that you're after.

Comment: I want to work on terrain attributes and used them in Spss. so I guess that I should bring them on Excel. Am I right?

Comment: But surely you don't mean that you want to bring an entire raster of an attribute (e.g. slope) into a spreadsheet. Are you aggregating the data in some way, e.g. the average slope for a group of drainage basins?

Comment: yes I want to bring the entire raster attribute

Answer (score 2):

Okay, here is a solution that will allow you to easily import Whitebox binary raster files into Excel. First, export the raster using the **Export ArcGIS ASCII Grid** tool (in fact any of the ASCII raster export tools will work fine).

[image]

Next, launch Excel and open the file, which will have the same name as your Whitebox raster file but with a .txt extension. A dialog will be displayed like the one below:

[image]

Be sure to select 'Delimited', press 'Next', and check the 'Space' box, as in below:

[image]

Press 'Finish' and you should be presented with a spreadsheet like the one below.

[image]

You can optionally delete the header part of the file contained in the first six rows of the spreadsheet. Please note that if you are working with a larger sized raster, working with the data in Excel may be extremely cumbersome and perhaps even impractical. Furthermore, depending on the version of Excel that you are using (pre-2007) you may be restricted to 256 columns and 65,536 rows.